# Can't get my Django form working

Tags: django, forms

I have no idea what's going on here: I thought I was implementing a very simple Django form, following the ContactForm example in the Django Docs (although I have used a different example for the forms.py). However, for some reason, when the page loads, I get the template, but no form appears. All the HTML is there as per the template, but the Django stuff (the form and `theTest` variable I've added) isn't rendered.

I'm half hoping there is a complication somewhere I'm unable to identify, however, I fear I've made a n00b error which I should be able to pick up......

If anyone can help me out, I'd be really grateful!

### My code:

**forms.py:**

```
class ContactSupportForm(forms.Form):
    fields = ('theSubject', 'theMessage')
    widgets = {
        'theMessage': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 55, 'rows': 12}),
        }
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
```

**views.py:**

```
from forms import ContactSupportForm

@login_required
def postSupportMessage(theRequest):
"""The new view to which the support form is submitted"""
isLoggedIn = linfiniti.isUserLoggedIn(theRequest)
if isLoggedIn == True:
    myRequestingUser = theRequest.user
    myRequestingUserEmail = myRequestingUser.email
else:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
if theRequest.POST:
    theForm = ContactSupportForm(theRequest.POST)
    if theForm.is_valid():
        theIssueSummary = theForm.cleaned_data['theSubject']
        theMessageDesc = theForm.cleaned_data['theMessage']
        theIssueDesc = '%s \n \n Username: %s \n \n User Email: %s' % \
            (theMessageDesc, myRequestingUser, myRequestingUserEmail)
        theIssue = json.dumps({
            "fields": {
                "project":
                      {
                      "key": "SUPPORT"
                      },
                "summary": theIssueSummary,
                "description": theIssueDesc,
                "issuetype": {
                     "name": "Bug"
                    }
                }
          })
        myRequest = urllib2.Request('http://MYURL')
        myAuthString = base64.standard_b64encode('%s:%s' % ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
        myRequest.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % myAuthString)
        theResult = urllib2.urlopen(myRequest, theIssue, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        myReturn = theResult.read()
        if myReturn:
            theNewKey = myReturn.key
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
                "success": True,
                "theNewKey": theNewKey
                }))
        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
                "success": False
                }))
    else:
        theForm = ContactSupportForm()
        theTest = 'crap'
else:
    theForm = ContactSupportForm()
    theTest = 'rubbish'

return render_to_response('contact-support.html',
                                     {
                                     'theForm': theForm,
                                     'test': theTest
                                     },
                                     context_instance=RequestContext(theRequest)
                                     )
```

**HTML:**

```
<h5>Contact Support</h5>
      <div class="buttons" id="reload-support-form">
        <a data-ignore="true" class="btn btn-mini" href="javascript:void(null);" id="show-sent" onClick="reLoadSupportForm();">
          <i class="icon-refresh"></i> Reload Form
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>{{test}}</h1>
    <div class="widget-content" id="support-message-container">
      <div id="message-support-content">
        <form action="" method="post" id="compose-message-form" class="form-horizontal">

{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in theForm %}
  <fieldset class="control-group {% if field.errors %}error{% endif %}">
    <label class="control-label" for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
    <div class="controls">
      {{ field }}
      {% if field.help_text %}
        <span class="help-inline">{{ field.help_text }}</span>
      {% endif %}
      {% if field.errors %}
        <span class="help-inline">{{ field.errors|striptags }}</span>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="support-message-submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

As per answers/comments below I've updated my forms.py (I've also removed the second `else` from the view):

```
class ContactSupportForm(forms.Form):
theSubject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
theMessage = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 55, 'rows': 12}))
error_css_class = 'error'
required_css_class = 'required'
```

However, I'm still not getting a form in the template and I'm not getting `theTest` in the template either. The view correctly returns the template, but it does not return the form or `theTest`.

Comment: Argh, please stop with the funnyJavaStyleVariableNames!

Comment: What's not to love about camelCase?! Works for me!

Comment: Your form class is wrong. Please read documentation again. I am not sure what you are doing there. There are no fields defined in your form.

Answer (score 1):

As Aamir points out, you have not defined any fields on your form and it's not clear where you got the idea to do it the way you have. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#form-objects) shows clearly what to do:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 55, 'rows': 12}))
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
```

The `widgets` and `fields` attributes are only used in the inner Meta class of ModelForms, which are forms generated from a model, when you want to override the default fields/widgets of fields on that model. You're not doing that here, so they make no sense.

Also, in your view, you should drop the second `else` clause: with that you're reinstantiating the form when there are validation errors, so the errors won't show on the HTML page. Dropping that clause will allow execution to drop straight through to the render_to_response call.

(And on the subject of variable names, quite apart from the camelCase issue I can't imagine why you feel the need to prefix half the variables with `the` and the other half with `my`. What information is that adding?)

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I've updated the question - despite changing forms.py, it's still not working. On the `the` and `my` subject, the idea is (not mine and I probably haven't got it quite right here yet) is to denote variables which belong to/are created by the function (`my`) or which are incoming/outgoing (`the`).... I haven't explained it very well... Needless to say, I don't normally do much of the Django coding. But the idea is to make the code easier to follow for anyone else. We use camelCase/descriptive words for the same reason. It may be stupid/unnecessary, but that's the way it is!